# Cross platform RPC integration for Corda?

Tags: corda

Are there any plans to develop `CordaRPCOps` for cross platform interaction, for example, will there, or is where a way I could connect to a Corda node using RPC from Python or .NET?

Comment: I have built a prototype which allows nodejs application to interact with Corda over RPC using GraalVM: https://github.com/nitesh7sid/cordapp-example-nodejs-server-graalvm
You can do this similar for python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, no, beyond JVM languages. See the message from Corda's lead platform engineer that he wrote to celebrate Corda's third birthday:

> I’ll ask for input again at the start of the Corda 5 cycle because
>   it’s very open to feedback, but here are some initial APIs we’re
>   thinking of upgrading:
>
> - ...
> - If there is interest and adoption, support for more languages like JavaScript, C++, C# … probably using a mix of Graal and conventional
>     code generation. We might start looking for contributors to ‘own’
>     optimizing the experience in these other languages, rather than the
>     Corda team taking it all on.
> - ...

In the meantime, you have several stop-gap options:

- Using GraalVM for supported languages, as Nitesh comments above
- Implementing a thin server that maps `CordaRPCOps` calls into HTTP methods (e.g. [Braid](https://gitlab.com/bluebank/braid))